# Remote XDebug in VS Code - multiple requests in call stack

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm using XDebug with VS Code, and it works flawlessly when I'm debugging something locally. I can step through the breakpoints of each request sequentially in a sane, logical manner.

However, if I try to debug something remote, the requests come in immediately and flood the call stack:

[image: XDebug call stack]

This makes things incredibly difficult to trace. In the middle of looking at a breakpoint, a new request will come in, the window will pop over to that breakpoint, and I'll lose my spot. Why is this happening?

Note: my remote setup is pretty simple:

- I'm using a simple SSH tunnel for port 9000 from the server to my local system
- The remote files are mounted to my local system using SSHFS, and I opened that location using VS Code
- In my `launch.json`, I have `pathMappings` configured to `"/remote/system/files": "${workspaceFolder}/"` so that the debugger knows where to look for the source.

Comment: "Why is this happening?" — That's hard to tell, as there just seem to be more PHP requests / scripts run at the same time. I see a `cron.php`, a `remote.php`, etc. To me it looks like it's just your application doing its normal things.

Comment: Not exactly. When the application is local, there is only ever one request in the call stack. Even if there are multiple requests, the IDE handles each request sequentially. The breakpoints trigger, and when all breakpoints have been hit, the next request is shown in the call stack. When it runs remote and there are multiple requests, they all flood the call stack and hit the first break point at once. Worse, if a new request comes in and hits a breakpoint, the screens snap back to that new breakpoint (taking focus away from where I was). It's truly annoying.

Comment: Okay, I take it back, and I partially figured out what's happening. After installing a full X server and VS Code on my remote system, the multiple request behavior is the same. That's when I realized the difference. On my local system, I'm using the PHP Server plugin to run my projects, and that is what prevents multiple requests from piling up. Any idea why this plugin works differently from a native nginx/Apache server? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver

Comment: OOOOooooohhhh - I get it. I need to be running my webserver in single process mode. In the case of Apache on Debian, that means `apache2ctl -X`. I'll edit my question and post a solution in a bit when I get a break.

Comment: This is another good candidate for "Max simultaneous connections" option https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/571